# Vertical fill with Angular Material & Flex

Tags: angular-material

How do I fill the screen vertically with e.g. a md-content or just a div? I still want to organize the content within as column.

```
<md-content layout="column" layout-fill>
  My content!
</md-content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a row with a flex attribute, it fills the screen vertically.

In the following example, "My content" will fill all available space (vertically and horizontally)

```
<md-content layout="row" flex>
    <md-content layout="column" flex>
        My content
    </md-content>
</md-content>
```

Answer (score 3):

Regarding *@stack item* answer angular material says:

> In general, `<md-content>` components are not designed to be nested inside one another.

So I would suggest changing the first `md-content` to a normal `div`.

```
<div layout="row" flex>
    <md-content layout="column" flex>
        My content
    </md-content>
</div>
```